# Nginx server block with both IP address and server name for virtual hosts

Tags: windows, nginx, virtualhost

I am having trouble with configuring virtual hosts with Nginx, and am wondering if that may be because of this remark in Nginx Http Server 2nd Edition, p.68

```
...creating server blocks that you identify either by a hostname
or by an IP address and port combination...
```

What I need is Nginx separating requests for two IIS web servers. Nginx is on the same windows machine as IIS, there are separate IP addresses for each IIS site and for Nginx. Nginx should only listen on its own IP address. Http requests on port 80 are returned with a 301 for https. Several domain names should get separate Nginx server blocks, that forward incoming requests to either one of the IIS sites with e.g. `proxy_pass` according to some rules. So I need to configure server blocks for each virtual host with both a `listen` and a `server_name` setting. But I am not getting it to work.

Am I on the wrong track? Is this only possible if Nginx is on a separate machine?

There are many advantages of having Nginx on a separate linux machine: e.g. performance. But this is a windows shop, so linux is not an option, so another machine for nginx just means extra cost and management overhead.

Comment: Nginx on windows machine is good for dev/review only. Windows support is still in beta stage. Why not just configure iis properly?

Comment: @AlexeyTen I'd like to utilize the unique strengths of Nginx in addition to IIS. But if Nginx cannot configure virtual hosts with both Ip address and servername, it may not be going to work for me. Can it?

Comment: It can. There are some pitfalls. Just use exactly the same ip:port pair for all servers that need to listen to the same port and nginx will choose server block by server name

Comment: Good explanation https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

Comment: I don't think @AlexeyTen warned strongly enough against using nginx on Windows in production. [It is significantly crippled compared to Linux](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html) or even IIS, and will have relatively low performance. If you are not running high traffic sites, this might not be an issue, but don't let being "a windows shop" stop you from using Linux. Even Stack Overflow, a Windows shop, uses Linux in certain performance-critical roles.

Comment: All: thanks for comments on linux versus windows, this might help me getting a linux for nginx. But for the main question: I am growing into the concept that for virtual hosting it might perhaps not be important to use `listen` commands for every `server_name`. When I am back at the office, I will explore this.